# Converting file in Oracle 11g (file system)

Tags: sql, csv, plsql, oracle11g, filesystems

I'm stuck on this situation, i've created a **concurrent program** that creates a txt file within some important information from a query. Everytime it runs it creates a different file and it is "saved" in a directory

My query looks like this (it is not completed, just wanted to show you how i format all the data using LPAD and RPAD):

```
SELECT trx.id_transaction,
       trx.number_account,
       Rpad(Nvl(trx.reference, ' '), 15, ' ')
       ||' '
       || Lpad(Nvl(trx.amount, ' '), 13, ' ')
       ||' '
       || Lpad(Nvl(trx.remaining_amount, ' '), 13, ' ')
       ||' '
       || Rpad(Nvl(trx.currency, ' '), 5, ' ')
       ||' '
       || Rpad(Nvl(trx.payment_detail, ' '), 4, ' ')
       ||' '
       || Rpad(Nvl(trx.code, ' '), 4, ' ')
       ||' '
       || Rpad(Nvl(trx.type_document, ' '), 2, ' ')
       ||' '
       || Rpad(Nvl(trx.number_customer, ' '), 10, ' ')
       ||' '
       || Rpad(Nvl(trx.doc_number, ' '), 15, ' ')
       ||' '
       || Rpad(Nvl(trx.line_id, ' '), 3, ' ')
       ||' '
       || Rpad(Nvl(trx.year, ' '), 4, ' ')
       ||' '
       || Rpad(Nvl(trx.deadline_payment, ' '), 8, ' ')
       ||' '
       || Rpad(Nvl(trx.remaining_days, ' '), 8, ' ')
       ||' '
       || Lpad(Nvl(trx.payment_bank, ' '), 13, ' ')
       ||' '
       || Lpad(Nvl(trx.last_info, ' '), 4, ' ')
       ||' '
       || Lpad(Nvl(trx.discount, ' '), 8, ' ') line
FROM   (SELECT rcta.id_transaction,
```

---

My file looks like this:

**TXT FILE:**

```
POL-45345334234       -963747       -963747 $   KAN  98   HU 554534     2179007             2021 20210127 20210127       -963747              
POL-99345552342        628308        423818 $   KAN  98   JU 999898     1402048             2021 20190104 20190208        423818   30        0
```

The problem comes in here, i dont know how to convert this file that was placed in a directory and replace the spaces by commas (commonly known as a CSV file).

> I want to get some automation, everytime a new txt file is placed in
> the directory convert the recent TXT FILE, obtain the CSV FILE and
> place it in a different directory. Do you get me?

I'd like to obtain something like this:

**CSV FILE:**

```
POL-45345334234,-963747,-963747,$,KAN,98,HU,554534,2179007,2021,20210127,20210127,-963747,,              
POL-99345552342,628308,423818,$,KAN,98,JU,999898,1402048,2021,20190104,20190208,423818,30,0
```

How can i convert a file stored in a oracle directory and obtain something like above?

What should i do?

Comment: How are you generating the file? Are you using UTL_FILE procedure calls, or spooling SQL*Plus commands, or something else?

Comment: Hey @pmdba thanks for replying!. I'm using UTL_FILE procedure. What would you do to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/generating-csv-files

Comment: The thing is: i would like to convert the TXT file that was generated and "saved" in the directory. Is it neccesary to create a PROCEDURE?. Can give me an example?. Suppose that my TXT file was placed in the directory: c:\oracle\myfiles. What should i do first?. I want to generate another file, a CSV one

Comment: Yes, you have to write a procedure or program of some kind. You'd have to parse the original file and do a row by row conversion, then write the file back out again. Efficiency would depend on your choice of scripting or programming language and your operating system. It may be easier just to have whatever database procedure makes the txt file also produce a csv file as an alternate output. It could even write both files at the same time.